# powershell script to generate trx report file

Tags: powershell, trx

I am trying to generate trx file as a report for the tests that I am running using powershell script. Currently I am generating html report using ConvertTo-html from PS but I am looking for generating trx report file.

Can anyone help?

Sorry if this is a very basic question. I tried searching everywhere and could not find answer.

Thanks for helping in advance.
-/Sammi

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at below link.

http://www.mytechfinds.com/articles/software-testing/6-test-automation/27-trx-to-html-using-xslt

Comment: Hi SavindraSingh,
I am looking for converting html to trx not the other way.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how are you creating html (what PowerShell commands you are using) from the tests?